# RedirectMatch & remove strings not working (stil shows ? at the end)

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to user RedirectMatch and remove strings, but the redirected url shows a ? at the end. The migration is from a folder to wordpress pages. I have many urls to redirect, so I'm redirecting them one by one only when ready, using the following htaccess code:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/effects_Dog.php http://www.website.com/folder/different-folder/dogs/?
```

The .htaccess is located inside website.com/folder/

It redirects, remove the unwanted strings, but shows final url with ? at the end: maybe because I'm on a subfolder (website.com/folder/), with the following htaccess rules?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)effects/(.*)\.php$ upload.php?name=$2&eff=effects [QSA,L]
```

Thank for your help

Comment: Use RewriteRule to redirect instead of RedirectMatch and the `?` wont remain.

Comment: Thanks. How should be with RewriteRule?